# Object creation variable construct values

Tags: php, oop, class, design-patterns, object

I am trying to figure out if there is a solution for the following problem:

Lets say I have a class named OpenFiles. The constructor requires a path to what file to open and an Object which is required for OpenFiles.

```
class OpenFiles
{
    public function __construct(Object $object,$filePath)
    {
        //code      
    }
}
```

The $object is always the same can could be found in some sort of container. But the filePath is different each time this class is needed.

My 'problem' is when this class changes I need to go over all my code and edit accordingly.

Is there a pattern or solution for this? or is this inevitable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need your $Object parameter .. please elaboratye

Comment: Could be a Config or Permission Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an interface for your object and use the interface as the input param for your function.

```
interface iPermissionCollection
{
    public function getPermission($name);
}
```

then change the class to use the interface instead of the object.

```
class OpenFiles
{
    public function __construct(iPermissionCollection $object,$filePath)
    {
        //code      
    }
}
```

and if you want to send a different class later just be sure that it will implement `iPermissionCollection`.

So the question is not how would i handle code refactoring if i chage the class constructor that i use multiple time but the question is how would i write such a class that uses exactly what it needs and then i could scale.